# Screen goes randomly black in OS X

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, display, screen

A Macbook screen goes black randomly, sometimes completely black and sometimes near black (you can still see the GUI).

This happens in OS X Yosemite and also during USB (Mavericks) (Yosemite) install wizards. However the screen remains perfectly bright in the boot selection menu.

**[You can see it clearly in this video.](http://youtu.be/9g0I9DM2s8k)**

[image]

As mentioned in the video the model is Macbook mid 2009.

**Issues:**

- F1 and F2 keys don't affect the brightness levels. However they
  appear to help to wake up the screen for short periods of time.
- Battery does not affect the screen state.
- The screen is always bright during the Boot selection menu.
- Screen rotation does not affect the display.
- Display brightness is set to 100% and Power options are set to max
  with or without battery.
- The problem started after upgrading Mac OS X Leopard to Yosemite.

Comment: To eliminate possible 3d party app doing that, start in Safe mode, hold shift key during boot. @bmike , this is not a answer, just troubleshooting :)

Comment: try pressing CTRL+OPT+CMD+T to see if it helps with dark screen.

Comment: @Buscar웃 thanks for your suggestions. Safe Mode behaves just like normal boot (lots of black screens), and CTRL+OPT+CMD+T doesn't seem to do anything so far.

Comment: OK, lets do some hardware test. Hold D key during start up.  https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18765?locale=en_US

Comment: Pressing D or OPT+D only works if the retail DVD is inserted, this message appears after the language selection: `Apple Hardware does not support this machine`. The DVD that came bundled with the Macbook is `Mac OS v 10.5.2 AHT v 3A140 Disc v 1.1 2Z691-6208-A`. Could Yosemite destroy the Apple Hardware compatibility?

Comment: Sounds like one of the display cables to me. Quite common issue on older white MacBooks. If it's the short one (from mainboard to inventer) it's not to expensive to swap. I'd recommend taking it to a repair center.

Comment: @KevinGrabher why would a cable fail exactly when OS X is booted and not during the Boot Manager?

Comment: Sorry I overread that with the boot menu. Does it work fine in the installed running system as well?

Comment: @KevinGrabher Not a single one. The problem started after upgrading to Yosemite, so I strongly believe that if I'm able to reinstall OS 10.5.2 the problem will go away, the Macbook restarts suddenly when I try to launch the retail 10.5.2 DVD. Now I will try with OS 10.6 and see how it works.